# Помогите с окончаниями

Tags: падежи

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться с окончаниями.

Есть следующее предложение:
Сзади в паре десятках километрах виднелись джунгли.

Пытаясь осмыслить правильную расстановку окончаний, я окончательно запутался.

- в паре десятках километрах?
- в паре десятков километров?
- в парах десятков километров?

В общем, я так долго вникал в звучание и суть, что окончательно потерял нить, помогите.

Comment: "Пытаясь осмыслить правильную расстановку **окончаний**, я **окончательно** запутался".  - A я, осмысливая **основы**, запутался **основательно**. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сзади в паре **десятков** (Р. п.) **километров** (Р. п.) виднелись джунгли.

Здесь нет грамматических числительных, пара, десяток ― это существительные с числовым значением. Поэтому управление Р. п., нет согласования.

Comment: А кто говорил про согласование? Или я что- то пропустила?

Comment: Благодарю. Вроде бы, разобрался.

Comment: Для варианта "в паре десятках километрах"  - это согласование в П.п., но такое согласование возможно только для грмматических числительных: в десяти километрах.

Comment: Вы меня простите, но ТАКОГО варианта согласования в природе не существует. Это грамматическая ошибка.

Comment: Так, если я правильно понимаю, Сибилла и написала, что было бы, **если бы было согласование. Но его и нету.**

Comment: Первый предложенный вариант: в паре десятках километрах, он НЕВЕРЕН, так как там использовно согласование в П.п. Откуда он взялся? По аналогии с правильным вариантом: (в чём) в десяти (П.п.) километрах  (П.п.), в трех километрах и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

"Сзади в паре десятках километрах виднелись джунгли".    В паре (чего?) десятков, десятков (чего?) километров. Кроме того, я бы выделила "в паре десятков километров" запятыми как уточняющее обстоятельство места. (Где?) - сзади, (где именно?) - в паре десятков километров.
Рискну предложить другой вариант. "Сзади, километрах в двадцати (именно в таком порядке, а не наоборот!), виднелись джунгли.

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант.

Comment: Да, Максим, когда Вы пишете, километрах в двадцати, Вы предполагаете приблизительное расстояние. Когда говорите: в двадцати километрах - это точное указание на дальность расстояния.

Comment: Кстати, user183861, а почему бы Вам не сменить произвольное имя на нормальное, ну хотя бы на ник? Так проще к Вам будет обращаться хотя бы или называть Вас. ;)

Comment: Артём, Вы читаете мои мысли.   С вашего разрешения обращусь к Вам на эл. почту с просьбой.

Comment: Хаха)) Рад буду с Вами пообщаться, только не знаю, чем я могу помочь...